# Getting dupicate entries while exporting the CSV report (Motopress Hotel Booking Plugin in Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-bookings

We have developed a Hotel Booking website in WordPress.

We have purchased the Motopress Alpenhouse theme and hotel booking plugin for our site. We are facing an issue while generating the CSV report. When we book 2 rooms under 1 booking/accommodation, we are getting duplicate entries of the whole row. i.e The issue is that the ‘Total’, ‘Paid’ and ‘Payment Details’ columns all show the total amount from the whole booking in each duplicate row, not the total for that specific room.

Therefore if we use it for auditing the financial reports, the totals will be incorrect. We are facing this issue every time when we book multiple rooms under 1 booking and generate the CSV report.

Please let us know how to fix this bug and stop the duplicate entries and rows while exporting the CSV reports.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the data.. Total is total amount not for room. And bcs you are booking 2 rooms will retunr it for each room. And so for the rest data. They dont provide list of hooks to point you in right direction where to modify it and since its premium plugin you should ask this question the author for best solution.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, my concern was even the total amount of both the rooms are getting duplicated in each row twice instead of the individual total amount